# What are the differences between compressor stations, pump stations, and booster stations?

Tags: gas, pipelines, energy

I am doing some research on impacts related to natural gas compressor stations. In some states, I've received data for compressor stations alongside other facilities in the oil and gas world. These booster stations and pump stations.

Before filtering out these other types of facilities, I'd like to make sure that I understand the difference between the facilities. Could someone outline key differences across these facilities?

Comment: So what research have you found so we don't spend time finding the same...

Comment: Well, I haven't found too much research on natural gas compressor stations. In truth, I'll be looking at things like economic impacts (e.g., jobs), environmental impacts (e.g., air quality), etc.,

Comment: I'm more interested in learning what the differences are between these facilities rather than impacts of them.

Comment: In the water/sewage world, pump stations raise the pressure (and thus the pipes go to higher strength pipes), while booster stations simply raise the elevation (so similar strength pipe, but under gravity flow).  Compressor stations don't exist as much, but that's because water is typically in compressible.  My hunch is the same in gas - booster just raises the pressure back to nominal level along a long pipeline, pump raise the pressure for travel, and compressor stations change the density to the point you can do cool things like filter out the contaminants.

Comment: I think the compressor station is to compress the neutral gas into fuel gas for storage and transportation. The pumping station is transporting the fuel gas through the pipeline. A booster station is to make up for the pressure loss due to long-distance travel in the pipeline.

Comment: what is your understanding of the differences? ... please add that info to your question

Answer (score 1):

Compressor stations are the main gas movers. Pumps would be for liquids. I guess 
"Booster" could be for either . Depending on situation , one location could have both a compressor and a pump for liquid and gas going the same area. There are many variations like one liquid line carrying diesel and gasoline to a producing area and a gas line and liquid line taking production out. Some locations may pipe out produced water to a location for treatment; significant When onshore US wells produce roughly 90% water ( not counting the production from fracking ). Although most produced water is reinjected in the same general area. And, the biggest compressor station I have seen, compressed gas for reinjection. Reading the question again, this sounds like the beginning of some more computer generated misinformation.

Comment: I was only thinking of produced or wet gas facilities. Dry gas going to market would be similar, but also with a variety of combinations.